# java - performing file operations on remote locations

Tags: java, file

hi
i want to perform operations on files like rename, copy and etc.
these are not local files. they are located on remote computers.

I have 2 options:
1. run some kind of a telnet client (a framework that i already have in my system) from the java code. connect to the remote computer and perform a cmd operation.
2. perform a regular java.io operation on the remote path.

the problem with 1 is that its not cross platform (only theoretical problem for me), and that i generally dont want to use this telnet framework.
the problem with 2 is that large operations on remote files is slower, compared to same operation being performed on the machine itself with telnet.

am i right?
any other options?
any additional inputs?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can deploy your application to the remote computer, you can simply write your own little client and server for these file operations.